# É possível chamar uma variável que não existe em Lua?

Tags: string, funções, variáveis, lua

A função "setmetatable" pode criar um item na tabela que não existe.
Mas é possível fazer algo semelhante quando uma variável que não existe é chamada?
Por exemplo (pseudocódigo):

```
setmetavariable(function() return true end)
```

Então sempre que nós usássemos, por exemplo, um "print" de uma variável que não existe, ela printaria "true" ao invés de "nil"

```
setmetavariable(function() return true end)
print(variavel_xyr) --"true"
```

Existe alguma função que faz isso em Lua ou não?

Comment: Não entendi os downvotes, a pergunta é boa.

Comment: Não votei negativo, minha tendência é votar positivo nessa questão. Mas acho que o título não é bom e falta especificar não ser uma atividade prática e sim apenas uma curiosidade técnica sobre a linguagem.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível com `setmetatable`. Quando você chama uma variavel não declarada, ela é buscada na tabela global(`_G`), do qual pode ser modificada como qualquer outra tabela:

```lua
_G = setmetatable(_G, {
    __index = function(t, k)
        return true
    end
})

print(variavel_xyr) -- "true"
```